# What is the difference between non-type template parameters in C++17 and C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, language-lawyer, non-type

Consider this code:

```cpp
using func = int (*)(int, int);

template<func F>
void do_something(int first, int second) {}

int something(int first, int second) { return 42; }

void  f()
{
  constexpr auto  function = something;
  do_something<function>(10, 20);
}
```

Which is compiled and run with C++17 standard compatible compiler, but it's fail with C++11 standard:

```sh
 error: no matching function for call to ‘do_something<function>(int, int)’
   17 |   do_something<function>(10, 20);
```

What is the difference between C++11 non-type template parameters and C++17 non-type template parameters? in §14.1.4 [temp.param][n3690]:

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
> — integral or enumeration type,
> — pointer to object or pointer to function,
> — lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> — pointer to member,
> — std::nullptr_t.

And in §17.1.4 [temp.param][n4713]:

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
> (4.1) — integral or enumeration type,
> (4.2) — pointer to object or pointer to function,
> (4.3) — lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> (4.4) — pointer to member,
> (4.5) — std::nullptr_t, or
> (4.6) — a type that contains a placeholder type (10.1.7.4).

The only difference is:

> < — a type that contains a placeholder type (10.1.7.4).

Which I don't think is related to my question because a placeholder type is something like `auto`, and I sent a value to template not a placeholder type or a type.

Comment: Does anything change if you write `constexpr auto function = &something;` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt, No, nothing change.

Comment: But naturally if you put `&something` directly into the invocation `do_something<&function>(10, 20)` then all is well?

Comment: Note that you are missing a return statement in `int   something(int first, int second) {}`

Comment: @BenVoigt, I tried `do_something<&function>(1, 1);` and `... function = &something; do_something<&function>(1, 1);`, but nothing changed.

Comment: @BenVoigt, Yes sorry about that, the MSVC compiler take that as a compile time error, i just remove it from my question for simplifying.

Comment: I mistyped that comment.  I meant `do_something<&something>(10, 20);` should work fine, proving the failure is related to the `constexpr` variable

Comment: @BenVoigt, Yes there is no problem with `do_something<&something>(1, 1);` or `do_something<something>(1, 1);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant difference is in the requirements on allowed template arguments (not template parameters) in [temp.arg.nontype].

C++11:

> A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:
>
> - ...
> - a constant expression that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates and function *template-id*s but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as `&` *id-expression*, except that the `&` may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding *template-parameter* is a reference; or
> - ...

[C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.nontype#2):

> A *template-argument* for a non-type *template-parameter* shall be a converted constant expression of the type of the *template-parameter*. For a non-type *template-parameter* of reference or pointer type, the value of the constant expression shall not refer to (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - a subobject,
> - a temporary object,
> - a string literal,
> - the result of a `typeid` expression, or
> - a predefined `__func__` variable.

In C++11, the *template-argument* `function` is not in the form `&` *id-expression*, and the name does not refer to the function `something`. It refers to a variable of type `int (*const)(int, int)`, whose value points at `something`. (And `do_something<&function>` wouldn't help, because now you have a pointer to pointer to function, which won't convert to the pointer to function type.)

In C++17, the syntax requirement is gone, and the restriction is a more relaxed purely semantic requirement on what objects can't be pointed at or referenced.

Comment: Could "now you have a pointer to pointer to function" be worked around without eliminating the variable by making a reference to function, and then in the template argument list applying `&` and naming the reference (the `&` naturally applies to the referent)?

Answer (score 3):

C++11 [temp.arg.nontype]/1:

> A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:
>
> - [...]
> - the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
> - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates and function *template-ids* but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as `&` *id-expression*, except that the `&` may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding *template-parameter* is a reference; or
> - [...]

In other words, the form that a non-type template argument may take in C++11, in the case of a pointer, is heavily restricted. You can directly name the entity pointed to, as in `&something`, or, since this is a function, you may omit the `&` and allow the function-to-pointer conversion to take place, but you cannot use the name of an object that contains the pointer value, even if it is a `constexpr` object.

In C++17, almost all restrictions of this type were removed. In particular, a template argument for a non-type template parameter of function pointer type can be any converted constant expression of the appropriate function pointer type.